# calculate probability matrix from a table

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data.frame as follows :

```
data <- read.table(text = 'Select.Actions,Current.State,Next.State
Hire new staff,Out of Benchmark,Withinbenchmark
Hire new staff,Out of Benchmark,Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer,Withinbenchmark,Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer,Withinbenchmark,Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer,Out of Benchmark,Out of Benchmark
Fire new staff,Out of Benchmark,Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer,Withinbenchmark,Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer,Out of Benchmark,Withinbenchmark
Fire new staff, Out of Benchmark,Withinbenchmar', 
                   header = TRUE, sep =",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I split data.frame into 3 separate list and I want to calculate transition probability matrix for each of them.

```
  z <- list()
  trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
  for(i in unique(data$Select.Actions))
  {
    z[[trim(i)]] <- data %>% filter(Select.Actions == i) %>% select(Current.State, Next.State) 
  }
  ###Condition must select 3 actions ####
  empiricala1<-z[1]
  empiricala2<-z[2]
  empiricala3<-z[3]

  #show(empirical) calculate transition probability from historical data
  em1<-as.data.frame(empiricala1)
  em2<-as.data.frame(empiricala2)
  em3<-as.data.frame(empiricala3)
  lis <- list(em1,em2,em3)
  tab1 <- table(em1)
  tab2 <- table(em2)
  tab3 <- table(em3)
  tab1<-addmargins(prop.table(table(em1$Current.State,em1$Next.State),1),2)
  tab2<-addmargins(prop.table(table(em2$Current.State,em2$Next.State),1),2)
  tab3<-addmargins(prop.table(table(em3$Current.State,em3$Next.State),1),2)

  transitionprob11<-p[,,1]<-prop.table(table(em1$Current.State,em1$Next.State),1)
  transitionprob12<-p[,,2]<-prop.table(table(em2$Current.State,em2$Next.State),1)
  transitionprob13<-p[,,3]<-prop.table(table(em3$Current.State,em3$Next.State),1)
  print(transitionprob11)
  print(transitionprob12)
  print(transitionprob13)
```

But when I run it the error message is that transitionprob1,transitionprob2 and transitionprob3 not found. 
Could you please advice me?

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you build functions outside `shiny` then make them interactive

Comment: I also wrote it outside of shiny but it does not work, I post my question in the format of shiny to tell the whole story o programmer.

Comment: The main problem is in the logic of TPM()

Comment: I don't think you have understood the problems to which a transition matrix approach might apply. You need to have a set of states that completely cover the possibilities for origin and destination. You would need to have a 2 column dataframe where the values in each column are a subset of that range of possible states. Perhaps you need to illustrate how you would construct your notion of a matrix from the tiny amount of data you have presented. You could construct three separate transition matrices, one for each 'Select.Action', but that didn't seem to be what was being requested.

Comment: you mean that I have to create 3 dataframes (for each action seperately) with 2 columns consists of set of possible states?

Comment: I have revised my question based on your comments, could you please take a look at it and tell me you suggestion.